# Youtrack is not updating issue state

Tags: intellij-idea, youtrack

I have installed Youtrack on my computer and Youtrack PLugin for Intellij IDEA. I connected Intellij IDEA to the Youtrack Server via Youtrack Plugin.
Plugin is retrieving issues from the server without any problem. But today I noticed that when I am setting some Youtrack task (issue) as an active I found out that component "Update issue state" is not showing any Issue State in dropdown menu.

[image]

Each time when I set task as an active one I update state to "In Progress", but now because of this problem I am setting it manually by Youtrack command or in Youtrack server.

It seems that I broke some configs of Youtrack Server or something else which I couldn't solve myself.

How to fix this?

Comment: Is there a field named "State" attached to the project?

Comment: @Jk1. Yes, I have already checked. It updates "State" successfully when I send command to Youtrack Server.